# Multi-site Group-pricing & Special Pricing

Tags: performance, multistore, price, tierprice

When creating group pricing on a multisite install, we just use ALL WEBSITES.

We have a lot of 'websites' but only 1 or 2 have special or customer group pricing.

In terms of speed & performance, is it better to apply group/tier pricing to ALL WEBSITES or specify the website? The latter seems to create fewer database entries.

Or does it not matter at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The price index will generate entries for each product/site/group combination, so it does not matter if you specify all sites or specific ones.